# Dynamically modify the bandwidth of a link in mininet

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, mininet

How can I dynamically change the bandwidth of link?

Scenario: there is a one link(l1) connecting two host h1 & h2 and I've the bandwidth traces. Now, I want to simulate this in link l1.

Question in another way, I want to change the bandwidth of link in regular intervals.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not supported yet! Follow https://github.com/mininet/mininet/pull/650. Unless you use TCLink to adjust bandwidth to the added virtual links, you can use Wondershaper to shape the bandwidth. https://ostechnix.com/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth-in-linux-using-wondershaper/